# overflow-y scroll not working in IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, web-applications

Hi I have registration form .I need  it to have a vertical scrollbar, I am using the below css:

```
.scrollbar{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height:400px;
}
```

The above code works for Firefox and Chrome but IE doesnt show up the scrollbar at all . Any idea how to fix this

Comment: Add a working example. It might be other things that affect this and cause the problem..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771902(v=vs.85).aspx

You can use

```
-ms-overflow-style:scrollbar;
```

Comment: For my case, -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar; worked

Comment: @T.Liu thanks, both of your answers did it

Answer (score 3):

Actually this only works as of 5/2018 to have the overflow div contain another element inside of it. The other solutions do not

This works

```
  <div style="overflow:auto"><p>{{largepiecetext}}</p></div>
```

This does not

```
  <div style="overflow:auto">{{largepiecetext}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Below code worked for me . have added overflow-x, overflow-y,min-height, max-height

`<div style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: scroll;min-height: 110px;max-height: 110px;">{{largepiecetext}}</div>`