# Apache Wicket Palette Scroll not working in IE11

Tags: html, scrollbar, wicket

I'm using Apache Wicket with HTML for rendering the `Palette`.
`Palette` is working fine with large data in chrome but when I open this in IE the scroll bar is not appearing.

This `Palette` is rendered by wicket component from java side there is no code in html.

[image]

Comment: What version of wicket ?

Comment: @soorapaman 1.5.3

Comment: @TaufikPirjade may I point out that 1.5.3 is not the latest release in the 1.5 branch? You should probably upgrade to 1.5.17 for security purposes and plan to migrate to 6 or 7 (since 8 will be also be released soon).

But to get back on topic, what version of IE are we talking?

Comment: What is a "pallet"?  Are you talking about a `<select multiple>`?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS yes its <select multiple>

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke i am using IE 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably asking about `org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.palette.Palette` component.

There is a bug in IE11 that may prevent `overflow-y: scroll` from working. If this is the case, there is a way to work this around: `-ms-overflow-style:scrollbar`. More info on this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771902(v=vs.85).aspx

(For the previous paragraph, kudos go to the answer here [overflow-y scroll not working in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890061/overflow-y-scroll-not-working-in-ie-11) )

Next, html markup for `Palette` component is available in Wicket; for version 1.5.3 it is here: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/wicket/releases/wicket-1.5.3/wicket-extensions/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/form/palette/Palette.html (it is better to download it manually and view using a text editor as svn.apache.org does not serve this as plain text).

The part of this markup corresponding to the right `<select>` tag follows:

```
    <td class="pane selection">
            <select class="selectionSelect" wicket:id="selection">[selection]</select>
    </td>
```

I'd suggest to try to add the following styles somewhere after Wicket's styles are added (for example, directly in a `<style>` section in your component/page):

```
table.palette td.pane select {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-style:scrollbar; /* to workaround IE11 bug */
}
```