# Menu item is overlaped when use flex in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This is my code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tuantai431997/y89nhLjd/3/)

My problem is that the item is overlapped when the width of the window changes to the size that it does not overflow.

When i use chrome

[screenshot for chrome](https://imge.to/i/ZXPUr)

When i use ie

[screenshot for ie](https://imge.to/i/ZX45A)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        ul {
            overflow: scroll;
            display: flex;
        }
        li {
            flex: 1;
            flex-basis: 0px;
            padding: 15px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            list-style: none;
            border: 1px solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item ABCDEF</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
        <li>item 6</li>
        <li>item 7</li>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
        <li>item 6</li>
        <li>item 7</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The similar issue I have found in below link. [overflow-y scroll not working in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890061/overflow-y-scroll-not-working-in-ie-11)

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't working, overflow working, the problem is that the width of li doesn't fit with content. You can see the img [img-error-ie](https://imge.to/i/ZtyET)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **overflow:hidden, text-overflow: ellipsis** , if the text is overflow then it will hide the content and added "..." in the **li** block.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the min-width property for the container and flex item, then, it will display the item with scrolls. Also, as Pavan Kumar said, you could hide the overflowed text using ellipsis.

Code as below:

```
<style>
    ul {
        overflow-x: auto;
        display: flex;
        min-width:1000px;
        list-style-position: inside;
    }

    li {
        flex: 1;
        flex-basis: 0px;
        padding: 15px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        list-style: none;
        border: 1px solid;

        min-width: 50px;
        -ms-flex: 1;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
</style>
```

the result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uk69.gif).