# How to get scroll in IE 11

Tags: html, css, sass

It's a CSS issue. I'm trying to get scroll if labels are overflowing. The problem is with Internet Explorer only and not with Firefox and Chrome. I checked this question:
[overflow-y scroll not working in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890061/overflow-y-scroll-not-working-in-ie-11).

Here's the screenshot from Firefox:

[image: layout in Firefox]

But this is not working for IE 11:

[image: layout in IE]

This is my scss:

```
.pt-tokens>ul.pt-token-list {
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    font-size: $font-size-16;
    line-height: 22px;
    max-height: $height-active-filters-tokens-cont;
    min-height: $height-active-filters-tokens-cont;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: $color-gray-245;
    outline: none;
    overflow: scroll;
   -ms-overflow-style: -ms-scrollbar;
}
```

This is DOM Explorer of IE 11:

[image: DOM in IE11]

I tried many solutions. I've also tried:

1. -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
2. -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;

```css
.fruit-wrapper {
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  max-height: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  outline: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="fruit-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Apple
    </li>
    <li>
      Bananna
    </li>
    <li>
      Mango
    </li>
    <li>
      Grape
    </li>
    <li>
      Orange
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle (the icon in the toolbar on this site that looks like `<>` ) so we can recreate your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This happens a lot because of spacing discrepancies between various browsers. Some may need scroll bars, while others may not (which can cause the bar to obstruct certain items).

Try using `overflow: auto;` to show the bar only when necessary.

Comment: I tried that also. In fact within the template I used `style=overflow: auto`. But it's not working.

Comment: Did you try adding extra padding around the "filters" container, as well as using `box-sizing: border-box;`? That can sometimes help

Comment: Yes, I tried this also after your suggestion. I'm still not getting scroll in IE 11.

Comment: Its hard to answer in that case. If you can show us a live example i will try to help you debug further

Comment: Ok. I'll try to create a stackblitz quickly.

Comment: Here's one stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tyq46p

Comment: The stackblitz is not working (showning apple and banana placeholder example)